# C++ array/pointer leak memory

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, esp8266

When I run function handleRequestWithParams(..) few times I am run out of RAM memory on my microcontroller (ESP8266). 
I am not sure that I should delete "paramsNames", "paramsValues" and maybe "values", or maybe I should create this arrays in other way?

```
struct RequestStructure {
    int paramsCount;
    String* paramsNames;
};

void Requests::handleRequestWithParams(RequestStructure requestStructure) {
    const int PARAMS_COUNT = requestStructure.paramsCount;

    String* paramsNames = requestStructure.paramsNames;
    String* paramsValues = readParamsValues(paramsNames, PARAMS_COUNT);

    _server.send(200, TYPE_TEXT, response(paramsNames[0], paramsValues[0]);

    //delete paramsNames;
    //delete paramsValues;
}

String* Requests::readParamsValues(String* paramsNames, int count) {
    String* values = new String[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        values[i] = server.arg(paramsNames[i].c_str());
    }
    return values;
}
```

Comment: You need to deallocate the dynamically allocated memory. The question is which function is the best place to do that. That can't answered without seeing the rest of your code. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), if you can.

Comment: I think that memory leak occurs only in readParamsValues(..) because of 'new' and I don't know how to delete values which I have to return from this function.

Comment: Elephant in the room: std::vector?

Comment: @SnowBizz You should check if `PARAMS_COUNT` is `> 0`.  Currently your code invokes undefined behavior on the `send` call if `PARAMS_COUNT == 0`.

Comment: @SnowBizz  Can you use `std::vector` in your application (since you stated you're working with a microcontroller)?

Answer (score 0):

Every piece of memory you acquire with `new` or `new T[]` must be deleted using `delete` or `delete[]` accordingly.

Otherwise you are leaking memory.

---

That said, I'd strongly discourage to deal with `new`/`delete` yourself.
Use either [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), or the classes from [Dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) of the c++ standard library instead.

These provide clear semantics how ownership of dynamic storage will be transferred between the distributed pieces of your code workflow, and manage the deletion automatically if the reference ceases to exist.

Comment: Yes, but I use only one 'new' and can't delete this because I return this value..

Comment: @SnowBizz You can delete it outside the function you've been allocating it. But that also depends on what `_server.send(()` actually does. If that function want's to operate on the asynchronously you'll run into problems. In the latter case `_server` should be responsible for deleting.

Comment: it is a synchronous method.

Comment: @SnowBizz Is it your code? Then provide the deletion there.

Comment: So adding a line: `delete []paramsValues;` at the end of `handleRequestWithParams(..)` will be OK and enough?

Comment: @SnowBizz Yes, in that case it's OK.